# Best way to create a voron RavenFS database in code?

Tags: c#, ravendb, ravenfs

In RavenDB 3.0, i want to create in code a new RavenFS database but in voron engine.
When the database doen't exist, it's created but un essent engine.

I tried this way :

```
FilesStore = new FilesStore
  {
  Url = "http://localhost:8080",
  DefaultFileSystem = "Test_FS"
  };
FilesStore.Initialize();
FilesStore.CreateOrUpdate("Test_FS");
```

Where Create or update is an extention function :

```
public static void CreateOrUpdate(this FilesStore filesStore, string databaseName)
    {
        try
        {
                       filesStore.AsyncFilesCommands.Admin.CreateOrUpdateFileSystemAsync(
                new FileSystemDocument
                {
                    Id = "Raven/FileSystem/"+databaseName,
                    Settings =
                {
                    {"Raven/FileSystem/DataDir", "~/FileSystems/" + databaseName},
                    {"Raven/FileSystem/Storage", "voron"},
                    {"Raven/ActiveBundles", ""}
                }
                }).Wait();
        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {
            var ex = e;
            throw;
        }

    }
```

I have to set the DefaultFileSystem name when i create the FileStore or it will crash during the CreateOrUpdateFileSystemAsync

So the FileStore is created once in essent, then transformed in voron in a second time... Ugly way...

Is there a better way to do this ?
Thanks

Whiletrue

Comment: The default option is to create it with Esent, but your second method should actually work for creating the fs with the right storage engine.
What happens if you just use that?

Comment: It crashes in the AsyncFilesCommands because the DefaultFileSystem is not set.

Comment: Oh, that has been fixed, please update to the latest.

Comment: Thanks ! Last question, can i use the ravenDB client 3.5.x with a 3.0 server ?